# Vuex Modal Store Best Practice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

so I'm building a calendar application and the user will be able to edit a booking in the calendar, and the booking editor will be within a modal popup.

I'm wondering what the best practice would be for the store for this. Should I create a BookingEditor store and hold the state and methods in there, or should this be part of the Calendar store?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends on the complexity of the code you're going to write. If it's just a few actions/mutations, I would stick to the calendar store. Working with multiple modules is great, but people tend to create way too many modules even when there's not an actual reason to

Comment: If you use your store ''modules 'namespaced', it's a very good way to keep your store code organised. Having many modules is not a bad practice. The nice thing is that you could easily interact between the namespaces if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to separate by concern. If you need to build a stateful Calendar in your BookingEditor, you could end up with quite some actions and mutations, so having a seperate place to handle those concerns would then be a good idea.

Vuex offers a nice way to create namespaces. So in your case I would suggest to create a store for your Calendar in a namespace like:

```
BookingEditor/Calendar
```

[Read more about namespacing in the vuex manual](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html)